# Reading simple json file from url in Android maven

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, maven

So I want to load a simple JSON file from a url using restTemplate.getForObject.
I have created a simple json file with just one string but android is unable to load it.
However, when I typ in the url in my emulators' browser, the browser shows my json file

Any idea why it is not working with restTemplate.getForObject?

My code:

ServerCaller:

```
private static final String ipAddress = "192.168.56.1:8080";
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
private String test;

private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters;

private static ServerCaller instance = null;

private ServerCaller(){
    messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters); 
}

private static void createMessageService(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new ServerCaller();
    }
}

public static ServerCaller getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        createMessageService();
    }
    return instance;
}


public ServerError getTest() {
        try {
         test = restTemplate.getForObject("http://" + ipAddress + "/ProjectTeamF-1.0/service/getTest.json", String.class);

        } catch (ResourceAccessException rae) {
            return ServerError.ServerNotFound;
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException hsee) {
            return ServerError.WrongData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ServerError.OtherError;
        }
        return ServerError.NoError;
    }

public String pakTest(){
    return test;
}
```

Then in my view:

```
serverCaller.getTest();
ServerError se = serverCaller.getTest();                        

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),serverCaller.pakTest(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d6ee90 that was originally bound here. It gives this error multiple times when I run the emulotar. But I think this is not te problem.. It just shows me an empty Toast

Comment: What's the MIME type your server's returning?

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean by MIME type?

Comment: Anybody that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to use AsyncTasks to get the objects with the url because you can't do this in the main thread.